# Keras: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset that has shape `X: (1146165, 19, 22)` and `Y: (1146165,)`. This is my model code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_valid, y_valid))

def create_model(shape=(19, 22)):
    tfkl = tf.keras.layers
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tfkl.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=shape),
        tfkl.LSTM(64),
        tfkl.Dropout(0.3),
        tfkl.Dense(64, activation="linear"),
        tfkl.Dense(1)
    ])
    
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer="adam")
    return model

model = create_model()
model.summary()
```

As you can see the `input_shape` is `(19, 22)`, which is right, but when I use `fit` I get the error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_15 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [19, 22]`
I search some answers on Stack, but most of them is because the input dimension is `(a, b)` instead of `(a,b,c)`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fit your model with a `tf.data.Dataset`, you'll need to make sure it is batched before using it in `model.fit`. For a `batch_size` of your choice, try

```
train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size)
model.fit(train_data)
```